# Linear Independence of a Span

Tags: linear-algebra, independence

If I have $({u,v,w})$ is a linear independent set, then for which values of $\alpha,\beta$ is $\{u,\alpha u +v,\beta v +w\}$ a linearly independent set?

I claim that for all $\alpha,\beta$ in $\mathbb{R} $ this holds.

Is this true?

My solution is:

$(\lambda _{1}+\alpha\lambda _{2}) u + (\lambda _{2}+\beta\lambda _{3}) v + \lambda _{3}w = 0  \implies $ 
$\lambda _{1}+\alpha\lambda _{2}=0$;
$\lambda _{2}+\beta\lambda _{3}=0$;
$\lambda _{3}=0$

By the last equation then, $\lambda_{2}=0$ and the same for $\lambda_{1}=0$, so the equation holds for any $\alpha,\beta$.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This is correct, but you have to start with $\lambda_1u+\lambda_2(\alpha u+v)+\lambda_3(\beta v+w)=0$.

Comment: So the final answer is correct???

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct, but I would add some explanation as to what $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ are and how you arrived at your equation (by taking a linear combination of $u,\alpha u+v$, and $\beta v+w$ with the coefficients $\lambda_1$,$\lambda_2$, and $\lambda_3$ and setting it equal to zero.).

Comment: So the final answer is correct???

Comment: That is the very first thing I wrote in my answer.